# Adding new developer to sandbox enabled application says 'pending'

Tags: facebook, submit, facebook-apps

Adding new developer to a sandbox enabled application displays 'pending' next to the invited Facebook user and the user never receives a confirmation email or anything which allows him to confirm adding himself as developer. Has anyone had this issue before. I found a bug reported which describes the issue, but its status is 'resolved'

I'll be glad for any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

the user you invited as developer/tester/admin has to accept this. send him to http://www.facebook.com/developers there he/she should see the confirmation notice.

Comment: Ok, I got there with the other user (the invitee one) and see the following line : 'You have a pending developer request.', where 'developer request' is a link. When I click on it it looks like there is some JS/AJAX check going on, which leads to nothing and I still can not accept the invitation...

Answer (score 2):

Also, as I discovered, the tester must be registered as Facebook developer to accept the invitation.